# How to get Button Coordinates for button in iOS Xamarin form

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have created below render to get the Coordinates.

I am getting X coordinates value, but Y coordinates value is always 0.

```
public class ContextMenuButtonRenderer : ButtonRenderer
{
   protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Button> e)
   {
      base.OnElementChanged(e);
       if (Element is ContextMenuButton contextButton)
       {
          contextButton.GetCoordinates = GetCoordinatesNative;
       }
   }

   private (int x, int y) GetCoordinatesNative()
   {
     return ((int)Frame.Left, (int)Frame.Top);
   }
}
```

How to get Y coordinate value ?

Comment: I believe that is returning the coordinates relative to the parent container, not the entire screen

Comment: So how can I get the coordinates of the button clicked?

Comment: @Jason Any info will be helpful.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Some context might help with understanding what problem you need to solve. What do you need those coordinates for?

Comment: I have a list of items. For each item I have added a 3 dot button. I am showing a pop up menu  on click of 3dot button. I need the coordinates so that I can display the popup menu next to the button click

Answer (score 0):

There is a relatively simple method in Xamarin.Froms. `AbsoluteLayout` can specify the position and child level. You can determine the coordinate position of the button when adding it, like this:

```
<StackLayout >        
    <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" />      
                
  <AbsoluteLayout>            
    <Button Text="111"  AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="80,100,50,20"/>           
    <Button Text="222" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="180,100,50,20"/>        
  </AbsoluteLayout>    
</StackLayout>
```

For more details, you can refer to the document: [Xamarin.Forms AbsoluteLayout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/absolutelayout)

**Update**:Touch Effects in Xamarin.Forms can get the touch coordinates, I tested the official sample can be obtained normally. You can refer to [TouchTrackingEffect Code](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/main/Effects/TouchTrackingEffect/TouchTrackingEffect), the `FireEvent` event in the `TouchRecognizer` class in the iOS part of the sample to convert the touch position into a point value. For more details about Touch Effects, you can check the official document: [Invoking Events from Effects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/effects/touch-tracking)

Comment: These are all dynamic buttons. I have a list where data is populated. On click of each item on the list, I want to show the pop-up menu. SO on run time I need to know the position where I clicked to adjust the pop up menu.

Comment: @abanisamal I updated my answer, you can try it.